# 400 Bad Request Posting Chatter Message

Tags: rest-api, chatter, jquery

I'm trying to reply to a private conversation in Chatter via the REST API, by making a POST request to `https://<<instance>>/services/data/v33.0/chatter/users/me/messages` using jQuery's `post()` method.

Whatever I do I keep getting an HTTP 400 response with the error message:

> "[{"errorCode":"MISSING_ARGUMENT","message":"Text parameter is missing or empty."}]"

The body I'm sending is valid, and I've tested it with workbench. The authorisation, content-type and accept headers have all been set to be the same as workbench too. Any idea of what this error is related to? I'm submitting the request like so, after setting the headers using `$.ajax();`:

```
$.post('https://c.na24.visual.force.com/services/data/v33.0/chatter/users/me/messages/',
  { 'body' : 'test from console', 'inReplyTo': '<<messageId>>'}, 
  function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: from what i remember about jquery it doesn't understand how send a json post, you need to use the actual serialized string as the payload param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that even though the docs say the message text should be in the `body` parameter:

[image: Image of the documentation showing the parameter is called 'body']

... and that `body` works as the parameter name in Workbench, renaming that parameter to `text` solves the problem!

```
 Object { body: "test - reply from the console.", inReplyTo: "<<message ID>>" } <- FAIL

 Object { text: "test - reply from the console.", inReplyTo: "<<message ID>>" } <- WIN
```